# How to use or supply AAC format audio in Google actions fulfillment

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-home

I am trying to play an audio stream for my Google home users. The richresponse with mp3 file works perfectly. But when I try to use an aac encoded file, the audio never plays.

Google home does support AAC audio format now. So any ideas why it doesn't play? Do we need to supply some other mediaType?

Could it be happening because Google assistant does not support aac format? But if that's the case, then which format do these other streaming companies use?

```php
$output = array (           
    "fulfillmentText"  => $Response,            
    "source"  => "My Stream",
    "payload" => array(             
        "google" => array (
                  'expectUserResponse' => false,
                  'richResponse' => 
                          array (
                            'items' => 
                            array (
                              0 => 
                              array (
                                'simpleResponse' => 
                                array (
                                  'textToSpeech' => $Response,
                                ),
                              ),
                              1 => 
                              array (
                                'mediaResponse' => array (
                                    'mediaType' => 'AUDIO',
                                    'mediaObjects' => 
                                    array (
                                      0 => 
                                        array (
                                            'name' => 'Sample stream',
                                            'contentUrl' => 'https://stream.test.com/117/full/64.aac'
                                        )
                                    )
                                )                         
                            )                   
                        )

                )
            )
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that the hardware for the Google Home [supports AAC](https://store.google.com/us/product/google_home_specs?hl=en-US), media responses via the Actions on Google client libraries [don't currently support AAC](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#media_responses):

> Audio for playback must be in a correctly formatted .mp3 file. Live
>   streaming is not supported.

Comment: The documentation has not been updated on the site but I have verified that it does play AAC audio. Just replace mp3 with aac file.

Comment: Can you share the source code for your project on Github?

Comment: Its just this script that I have shared in my question, @MaxWiederholt . Rest of the logic is on dialogflow